# Regex using negative lookahead missing first character of group2

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds

I need to get the LDAP group names from this example string:

```
"user.ldap.groups.name" = "M-Role13" AND ("user.ldap.groups.name"= "M Role1" OR "user.ldap.groups.name" = "M.Group-Role16" OR "user.ldap.groups.name"="Admin Role"  ) AND "common.platform" = "iOS" AND ( AND "ios.PersonalHotspotEnabled" = true  ) AND "common.retired" = False
```

I'm using this regex to match the parts of the string that contains an LDAP group

```
("user\.ldap\.groups\.name"?.=.?".+?(.*?)")(?!"user\.ldap\.groups\.name")
```

but it is matching in group2 the name without the first character.
https://regex101.com/r/2Aby6K/1

Comment: Welcome to SO! How about `/"user\.ldap\.groups\.name"\s*=\s*"(.*?)"/`? Not sure if it's necessary to capture group the whole pattern and the last negative lookahead seems pointless since the non-greedy `(.*?)"` terminates at the last `"` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes about the pattern you tried

- The reason it misses the first character is because this part `.+?` requires at least a single character
- Note that in this part `"?.=.?"` it matches an optional `"`, an equals sign between any char due to the dot where the second dot is optional and then `"`
- This part `(.*?)")(?!"user\.ldap\.groups\.name")` uses a non greedy dot `.*?` which will give up as least as possible to satisfy the condition to match a `"` which is not directly followed by `user.ldap.groups.name`. See [an example](https://regex101.com/r/Zr0WCo/1) of an incorrect match.

---

What you might do is use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

```
"user\.ldap\.groups\.name"\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"
```

In parts

- `"user\.ldap\.groups\.name"` Match
- `\s*=\s*` Match `=` between 0+ whitespace chars on the left and right
- `"(` Match `"` and start capturing group

  - `[^"]+` Match any char except `"` 1+ times
- `)"` Close group and match `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uiiKk8/1)

---

Or if you want to include the negative lookahead:

```
"user\.ldap\.groups\.name"\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"(?!"user\.ldap\.groups\.name")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6SvWi4/1)